# Is there a Wordpress contact form plugin where I can use my own form?

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking at a lot of very good Wordpress plugins which send emails/save to a database from a contact form, but all of them seem to reduce the form itself to a shortcode and the same with the fields.

For example you would create the form using something like:

```
[input field "your name"]
[checkbox "yes/no"]
```

and then insert it using

```
[myform_23]
```

but then you've got no control over the fields themselves, their classes, IDs, and so on, for instance to integrate with Bootstrap I want `class="form-control"` on each input, and similar things for the `<form>` and `submit` elements.

Is there a form plugin where I can have control over all those things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It you need a lot of control over your form look into [Formidable](https://formidablepro.com/) or [Contact Form 7](http://contactform7.com/). Contact Form 7 is free & has numerous add ons (both paid and free) and Formidable has a free option (with limited functionality) and is similar to Gravity Forms in its data management abilities.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 form-group">[input field "your name"]</div>
<div class="col-md-6 form-group">[checkbox "yes/no"]</div>
</div>
```

This is how you can add structure to a CF7 form.

Comment: Haven't tried Formidable. But Contact Form 7, for the sake of people who come along, definitely *doesn't* have this property. There are numerous DIVs added around the fields. You can add your own HTML but it will still be wrapped in the plugin's DIVs.

Comment: Take a look at what I added to my answer.

Comment: I'm aware I can add my own HTML.  What I'm asking is, how can I *remove* the HTML which the plugin adds. Any answer you give me which tells me how to *add more* HTML is an unsatisfactory answer.

Comment: Um, the plugin only ADDS what you specify the form to contain. There is a minimal amount of CSS built in for validation (which can be changed/removed). So as far as removing HTML the plugin ADDS to a form, that statement simply doesn't make sense given that YOU add all INUTS into it's editor that you want your form to be comprised of. You should take the time to read the documentation or try it out for yourself so you understand how it actually works.

Comment: I apologise! You're totally right. Contact form 7 is exactly as you say. I was confused with Fast Secure Contact Form. I will edit.

Answer (score 1):

Have you check out [Gravity Forms?](http://www.gravityforms.com/) 
They're pretty much the leading wordpress plugin for form management and control right now. It looks like [there should be a way to do what you want.](http://www.gravityforms.com/features/styles-layout/) You might want to give the demo a try.

Comment: Haven't "checked it out" because it's a paid extension, isn't it? And your link to "there should be a way" only shows me that I can add classes and IDs and inline styles. That's not what I need.

Comment: You have your answer, but I wanted to add that I did say "You might want to give the demo a try." So you could have in fact checked it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use contact form 7 along with contact form DB. this form will sends the email and saved the fields to the db as well. You can use your won class and id for each input field.
[Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/)
[Contact Form DB](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-to-database-extension/)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use my own class or ID. I want to use my own HTML.